# Power BI switch Relationship in measure?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a Power BI measure that calculates the cost of all active projects in my portfolio. I want to use it to show how cost will change over time. I have pasted the measure below. the problem is my date table's relationship with my project table is connected to the wrong column (I want date and 'Start Date' to be connected) but I can not change the relationship because the model the dashboard is built on is downstream meaning I can't open the power query editor, add a new table, or adjust relationships (without adding a local model which I do not want to do). Is there anything I can do to remedy this?

Current Measure

```
Active Cost = 
CALCULATE(
    [Cost Measure],
    'Projects Table'[Start Date] <= MAX('00DateTable'[Date]),
    'Projects Table'[End Date] > MAX('00DateTable'[Date])
    ||
    ISBLANK('Projects Table'[End Date])
)
```

Ive tried crossfilter, userelationship, and related /related table

Comment: How do you know how costs are changing? What's the DAX for [Cost Measure]?

Comment: Use TREATAS function: https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/physical-and-virtual-relationships-in-dax/

Comment: @Pieter the cost measure is just a sum() of the column. The three relevant columns from the project table are start date, end date, and cost. its like me trying to plot how many guests are at a hotel at any given time. some stay longer than others and some rooms have more guests than others

Comment: I gotta do it, but I'd explode the ({StartDate...EndDate}, Amount) so that you end up with (Date, Amount), and then it's just a normal total.

Comment: @Pieter figured it out. I dont entirely understand it but adding REMOVEFILTERS('00DateTable'[Date]) fixed it.

Comment: Oh right. Duh. REMOVEFILTERS(...) basically removes the join to the date table, so the evaluation context becomes "all the dates in the calendar" and then this
    'Projects Table'[Start Date] <= MAX('00DateTable'[Date]),
    'Projects Table'[End Date] > MAX('00DateTable'[Date])

Comment: What I was trying to say was that the comparison to MAX adds a new expanded evaluation context to your measure. =)